# Problem with Settings API: changes are not saved after submit

Tags: admin, api, options

I'm writing a plugin "Paid Post" with some options. I made a settings page for my plugin, and it displays OK, but when I'm pressing "save changes" button, the option I have do not change, it just stays "on".
Reading "Settings API" page didn't help, neither did exploring other plugins.
Sections of code for admin options:

```
// Admin options

function PPOptionsPage() {
  add_settings_section("section_main", __("Main options", 'paid-posts'), '', "paid-posts");

  add_settings_field(
    "pp_display_excerpt",
    __("Display post excerpt on a single page before paywall text", 'paid-posts' ),
    "PPCheckbox",
    "paid-posts",
    "section_main",
    array( 'label_for' => 'pp_display_excerpt')
  );
  register_setting("paid-posts", "pp_display_excerpt");
}

function PPCheckbox($options)
{
  echo '<input type="checkbox" class="code" name="'. $options['label_for'] .'" id="'. $options['label_for'] .'" value="1"' . checked(1, get_option($options['label_for']), false) . '>';
}

add_action("admin_init", "PPOptionsPage");

function PPAdminMenu() {
  add_options_page( 
    __('Paid Post options', 'paid-posts'),
    __('Paid Post', 'paid-posts'),
    'manage_options',
    'paid-posts',
    'PPAdminOptions'
  );
}

function PPAdminOptions() {
  if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
    wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
  }
  ?>
      <div class="wrap">
         <h1><?php echo get_admin_page_title(); ?></h1>

         <form method="post" action="">
            <?php
               settings_fields("section_main");

               do_settings_sections("paid-posts");

               submit_button();
            ?>
         </form>
      </div>
   <?php
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'PPAdminMenu' );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to register the proper settings fields in your `PPAdminOptions()` and also point the form action to `options.php`:

```
function PPAdminOptions() {
if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
    wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
}
?>
<div class="wrap">
    <h1><?php echo get_admin_page_title(); ?></h1>

    <form method="post" action="options.php">
        <?php
        settings_fields("paid-posts");

        do_settings_sections("paid-posts");

        submit_button();
        ?>
    </form>
</div>
<?php
}
```

I tested this on my local machine, and it saved the checkbox state.